# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to fr.pc30.bean.Intervention

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an error with `java.math.BigInteger` cannot be cast to a class name.

This is my request

```
public List<Intervention> findTicketTaskAnnuler(long partnaireId,InterventionType type) 
return   getSession().createSQLQuery(new StringBuilder("")
                .append("SELECT i.id FROM intervention i ")
                .append("INNER JOIN logged_event lo on lo.NEW_ID = i.id and lo.OPERATION ='ANNULATION' and lo.DATE_CREATION =CURDATE() and lo.USER != :name ")
                .append("WHERE i.ID_PARTENAIRE = :partnaireId ")
                .append("and i.annulee=1 ")
                .append("order by i.id desc ").toString())
                .setParameter("partnaireId", partnaireId)
                .setParameter("name", type.getName())
                .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `findTicketTaskAnnuler` is a `List` of `Intervention`, but in your query you specify

```
SELECT i.id FROM intervention i
```

essentially only selecting the id (that i suppose is a `BigInteger`)
so hibernate returns that type and your code try to cast it to `Intervention` class

Change your return type as `List<Long>`
or change your query to get all the fields you need to map to the entity

Comment: thank you but if i change select i from intervention i but still error

Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Comment: thank you but if i change select i from intervention i but still error Unknown column 'i' in 'field list' – Makkaoui Ahmed 7 mins ago

Comment: oh sry i missed that it was sql query... well anyway yes you can only change the return type then, cause you are selecting only a biginteger and not an entity

Answer (score 0):

Your query is getting list of ids (which I guess has bigInteger datatype) and you are trying to store your query output to list of `Intervention` object either change your list to `List<Long>` or change query to select all the columns with `SELECT *` query.

Comment: if u make list<Long> with select * so u cant cast java.math.long to object 
i find a solution is change ur return to List<Object>   
thank you :)